# Decorator function to wrap a function?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, ray

I have to write a dummy function to get my code running on different systems, from which some don't have the needed packages. The function is wrapped and then called like a `class`-function. I am struggling with this problem, any ideas how to do that?

Here I got a short snippet, I import a python script `ray.py` which should contain this `remote()` function. The `remote` function has to take two arguments, without any usage.

Edit: The`@ray.remote()` wraps the `run()` function to be parallel executable. It doesn’t change the return of `run()`. On some systems `ray` is not supported and I want the same script to execute sequentially without changing anything. Therefore I `import` a `ray`-dummy instead of the real one. Now I want to write the `ray.remote()` to wrap the `run()` function in a way so that it’s callable with `run.remote()`.

That may be a very inconvenient method to just sequentially execute a function, but necessary to achieve an easy integration for different systems.

```
# here the wrapped function
@ray.remote(arg1, arg2)
def run(x):
    return x**2

# call it
squared = run.remote(2)
```

Comment: "run.remote" refers to a method of the function object "run" (or whatever "ray.remote(...)" returns). This could be realized but doesn't make much sense. You should try to explain better what you want.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem: the code has to be this way to run parallel with ray. Somehow the decorator function packs the run-function into an object/class containing the function itself as 'remote' and that's where I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

I got a working script, located in the ray.py file:

```
def remote(*args, **kwargs):
    def new_func(func):
        class Wrapper:
            def __init__(self, f):
                self.func = f

            def remote(self, *arg):
                out = self.func(*arg)
                return out
        ret = Wrapper(func)
        return ret

    return new_func
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the @ray decorator in your answer.

Comment: The remote function is the decorator called in my minimal example. It’s located in ray.py and called with @ray.remote(...)